# List view get item back

Tags: android

I am displaying the list of items in listview(assuming that main category), once i click the items, it shows the sub_category. and again i clicked the subcategory of item, it goes to next activity. My question is whenever i clicked the subcategory and again i click back button in emulator, items in main category will not be displayed.

Comment: Probably because you did something wrong in your code. Which i cant see from here :\.

Comment: May be, but it displays all Items. also whenever i clicked it shows subcategory Item. My point is i want to show the main category data when i click back from subcategory Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make use of Intent Flags such as Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to go to new sub activity and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT to go back to previous activity.

Comment: Hey hope your answer might correct. But i cant understand exactly. can you explain once again. and please trigger out some examples..

Comment: check again [http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

Comment: whats that... nothing ill found.!! can you paste it again.

Comment: Yeah sure, Hey this concept is done through various activity which we calling concurrently to getting into an action. But my logic is, i am using lisview. let consider a single listview which shows both main category and subcategory from the database. so when i click back from sub_category in a listview, then it should represent the main category. But what i am getting is,it directly shows some other activity insted to show main category of list view.

Comment: I dont have anything right now. Hope you may understood my problem. pls let me the solution